# Whats wrong with my JavaScript AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chat

I am attempting to make a simple chat system which loads a new message when a new message exists. Previously, I just loaded all the messages from the database. I need to have the scroll bar scroll to bottom when a new user sends message.

Using this method accomplished the chat loading, but I was unable to scroll as it would go to the bottom every 200ms.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    setInterval(function() {$('#chatlog').load('logs.php');
    var chatReload = document.getElementById("chatlog");  //This is the scrolling part
    chatReload.scrollTop = chatReload.scrollHeight;  ////This is the scrolling part 
    }, 200); //AJAX updates 200ms
});
```

The new JavaScript code loads the previous messages. But does not load any new messages until I refresh the page. Upon refreshing the page the messages are all loaded but again won't load any new messages again. Why isn't this working? Thanks.

HTML and JavaScript:

```
        <div id="tab3">
          <h2>Chat Room</h>

                <div id="c-input_wrap">
                    <div id="chatlog">
                        Loading chat please wait...
                    </div>

                <div id="chatwrap">
                    <div id="chatinput">
                    <form name="chatbox" class="userchat">
                        <input class="userchat" name="message" type="text" autocomplete="off" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('chatbutton').click()" autofocus/><br>
                        <input class="userchat" id="chatbutton" name="submitmsg" type="button" onclick="submitChat()" value="Send" />
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<script>    
    var form = document.querySelector('form[name="chatbox"]');
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    function submitChat() {
        if(chatbox.message.value == '') {
            alert('Error: Missing Fields.');
            return;
        }
        var message = chatbox.message.value;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==100) {
                document.getElementById('chatlog').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open('GET','chat.php?message='+message, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        chatbox.reset();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.ajax('logs.php', {
            ifModified: true,
            complete: function(jqxhrResponse) {
                $('#chatlog').html(jqxhrResponse.responseText);
                // scroll to the bottom here
                scrollToNewMessage();
            }
        })
    });

    var allowScroll = true;
    $('#chatlog').scroll(function() {
        allowScroll = isNearBottom();
    });

    function isNearBottom() {
        var leeway = 10;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            return $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - leeway;
    });
}

function scrollToNewMessage() {
  if (allowScroll) {
    $("#chatlog").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chatlog').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
  }
}
</script>
```

chat.php:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    session_start();

    if  (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $userLabel = $_SESSION['nickname'];
    }

    $connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
    mysqli_select_db($connect, "root");
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $date = date('m/d/y');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    mysqli_query($connect, 
                "INSERT INTO chat (name, message, time, date) 
                 VALUES ('$userLabel', '$message', '$time', '$date')"
                 );

    $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER by id");
    while ($extract = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        echo $extract['name'] . ": " . $extract['message'];
    }
?>
```

logs.php:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    session_start();

    if  (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $userLabel = $_SESSION['nickname'];
    }

    $connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "root");
    mysqli_select_db($connect, "root");
    $day = date('m/d/y');
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * 
                                       FROM (SELECT * 
                                             FROM chat 
                                             WHERE date = '$day' 
                                             ORDER BY id DESC 
                                             LIMIT 100) x                                      
                                       ORDER BY id ASC
                                       ");

    while ($extract = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
            echo "
            <div class='usermessage'>
                <div class='mheader'>
                    <h1 style='color:".$color."'>" . $extract['time'] . "</h1>
                    <h2 style='color:".$color."'>" . $extract['date'] . "</h2>
                    <h3 style='color:".$color."'>" . $extract['name'] . "</h3>
                </div>
                <p>" . $extract['message'] . "</p>
            </div>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: please narrow down your code and add relative code which is causing error...

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: In your PHP your `$date` isn't in `mysql` date format; `yyyy-mm-dd`. Not sure how far your code is making it yet though; could you elaborate on how far in the process you are making it? You also are open to SQL injections with this code..

Comment: Console checks out fine. Why is it just important to use `mysql` date format? I have modified my question which to be more specific and where I am stuck at.

Comment: Because `2015-12-01` != `12/01/2015`. Is `date` a `date` column in your DB?

Comment: Yes, date is a date column in my DB

Comment: So `SELECT *  FROM chat WHERE date = '$day' ORDER BY id DESC` will never match up because the `date` in your datebase is `yyyy-mm-dd`, your date in PHP will be `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. The date is a varchar column. So in my database the date is in `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: @jcuenod Sorry. I won't be. I have deleted. You know why.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is put the messages into a JSON format on the PHP side and put an id with each message, when you pull in the messages set a last_message_id variable to the last id on that. This way you can request only the messages that are new since that last id.

Also, you should only scroll to the bottom of the messages if the user was there  you can set a variable to keep scrolling with new messages, but then when the user scrolls up, set it to false so it won't keep scrolling down.